# When I click on Invoice/Ship in Magento 2 Backend, It shows like this

Tags: magento2, backend

[image]

Magento 2 backend shows screen like this, all messed up, when I click Invoice or Ship Button.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually because a PHP error has occured, check your PHP logs or right click and view source, to see the actual error.